# Wifi adhoc network creation

Tags: raspbian

I am trying to create wifi Ad-hoc network/ Hotspot in pi but no success.

I tried from following links

- novitiate.co.uk/?p=183
- lcdev.dk/2012/11/18/raspberry-pi-tutorial-connect-to-wifi-or-create-an-encrypted-dhcp-enabled-ad-hoc-network-as-fallback/
- sirlagz.net/2013/02/10/how-to-use-the-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-pointrouter-part-3b/

Error are as follows:

Starting advanced IEEE 802.11 management: hostapdSegmentation fault

Debug : When I googled for the above error , some forums suggested to hardcode the path of wifi adapter driver. 
but when I hard-coded I am encountering the new error "Starting advanced IEEE 802.11 management: hostapdrmdir[ctrl_interface]: Operation not permitted
Segmentation fault
"

Conclusion : I am not able to start the hostapd service .

Comment: What wifi network adapter are you using ?

Comment: Netgear G54/N150 WiFi

Comment: Hm might need the chipset of the adapter. I'm not familiar with that one.